# This program is supposed to be recursive and give me all the possible sums of an array of integers

Tags: java, recursion

but I am getting duplicated answers when my array size is more than 2

```
 public ArrayList sum(int[]array, int arrayIndex, int newArrayIndex){

   if (arrayIndex<array.length){
       if (newArrayIndex<pow(2,arrayIndex)){
         if(newarray.isEmpty()){
           newarray.add(0);
         }
       newarray.add(newarray.get(newArrayIndex)+array[arrayIndex]);
       sum(array,arrayIndex,newArrayIndex+1);
       sum(array,arrayIndex+1,newArrayIndex-newArrayIndex);
       }
   }
   return newarray;
```

}

For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] numarray ={1,2,3};
   NumbersAddition num = new NumbersAddition(numarray);  
   num.sum(numarray,0,0);
}

output:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Should be: 0,1,2,3,3,4,5,6
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Why do you pass your array to the constructor and to your method again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're proceeding to the next `arrayIndex` once for each element you add.

You should instead do it once for each time you've gone over the entire newarray.

Here's your program with the minimal changes needed to make it both standalone and work the way you want:

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;

class NumbersAddition {
  ArrayList<Integer> newarray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  NumbersAddition(Object unnecessary) {}

  public ArrayList sum(int[]array, int arrayIndex, int newArrayIndex){
     if (arrayIndex<array.length){
       if (newArrayIndex<pow(2,arrayIndex)){
         if(newarray.isEmpty()){
           newarray.add(0);
         }
         newarray.add(newarray.get(newArrayIndex)+array[arrayIndex]);
         sum(array,arrayIndex,newArrayIndex+1);
       } else { 
         // Just do this when newArrayIndex has reached the end:
         sum(array,arrayIndex+1,newArrayIndex-newArrayIndex);
       }
     }
     return newarray;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] numarray ={1,2,3};
     NumbersAddition num = new NumbersAddition(numarray);
     num.sum(numarray,0,0);
     System.out.println(num.newarray);
  }
}
```

By the way, this code is a tail recursive rewrite of two nested for loops.

The more canonical recursive solution is to have a `sums(array, length)` defined in terms of `sums(array, length-1)` with `sums(array, 0) = {0}` as your base case.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am just starting with recursion now and it is kind of hard. I am going to try to do it also using the more canonical recursive solution as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `sum` should only happen if your second condition (`newArrayIndex < pow(2, arrayIndex)`) doesn't satisfy.

**Hints:**

- Instead of always checking if your list is empty, just add  0 at initialization.
- You know beforehand the size needed for you new array. Instead of a list, you could create an array with length `Math.pow(2, array.length)` and add your elements in position `pow(2, arrayIndex) + newArrayIndex`. This outperforms calling `add` over and over again.

**Edit:** I've made an implementation using an array and an additional method to hide the initialization details:

```
private static void sumAux(int[] array, int i, int[] powerSet, int j)
{
    if (i < array.length)
    {
        int pow = (int) Math.pow(2, i);
        if(j < pow)
        {
            powerSet[pow + j] = powerSet[j] + array[i];
            sumAux(array, i, powerSet, j + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            sumAux(array, i + 1, powerSet, 0);
        }
    }
}

public static int[] sum(int[] array)
{
    int[] powerSet = new int[(int)Math.pow(2, array.length)];
    sumAux(array, 0, powerSet, 0);
    return powerSet;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = {2, 3, 7, 13};
    int[] powerSet = sum(array);
    for (int i : powerSet)
    {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```